# Navbar not working like on the other subpages

Tags: html, css, navbar

I got a website where I have a couple of subsites. All connected with a navbar. This navbar is styled with CSS and connected with a class to an unordered list. As I'm adding a new Subpage and want to add the CSS to the navbar, it makes the background of it really tall.

[image: Homepage]

[image: New Subpage with ugly navbar background but the exact same code!!!]

I tried to create an additional class for this "special navbar" and copied and pasted the CSS code of the original class in the new "special class". After I did this I tested it but the CSS code didn't even do anything. If anyone could help me I would flutter.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.li {
  float: left;
}

.a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: white;
}

#active {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  color: black;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="li"><a href="index.php" class="a">Home </a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="stundenplan.php" class="a">Stundenplan SJ 22/23</a></li>
  <li class="li"> <a href="infos.php" class="a">&uuml;ber mich </a></li>
  <li class="li"> <a href="seiten.php" class="a"> Meine Lieblingsseiten</a></li>
  <li class="li"> <a href="formular.php" id="active" class="a"> Taschenrechner</a></li>
  <li class="li" style="float:right"> <a href="https://www.stocki.sg-hdh.de/" target="_blank" class="a"> Beispielseite Herr Stocki </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I put your code in a demo snippet. Does it show the problem? Please revise as needed. If we can't see the issue we can't help. Also, take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

Comment: You should become familiar with your browser's developer tools. It's easy to inspect elements to see what styles are applied.

Answer (score 0):

never use float unless you absolutely have to.  Use flexbox for your nav

```css
.nav {
display:flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}



.a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  color: white;
}

#active {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  color: black;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="li"><a href="index.php" class="a">Home </a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="stundenplan.php" class="a">Stundenplan SJ 22/23</a></li>
  <li class="li"> <a href="infos.php" class="a">&uuml;ber mich </a></li>
  <li class="li"> <a href="seiten.php" class="a"> Meine Lieblingsseiten</a></li>
  <li class="li"> <a href="formular.php" id="active" class="a"> Taschenrechner</a></li>
  <li class="li" style="float:right"> <a href="https://www.stocki.sg-hdh.de/" target="_blank" class="a"> Beispielseite Herr Stocki </a></li>
</ul>
```